Zabbix JSONpath LLD Discovery
I am trying to make discovering instances from https request. I have json like this:
{
  "count": 2002,
  "next": "http://.../circuits/circuits/...",
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 2620,
      "url": "http://.../circuits/circuits/2620/...",
      "display": "29278",
      "cid": "29278",
      "provider": {
        "id": 14,
        "url": "http://.../circuits/providers/14/...",
        "display": "AeroNet",
        "name": "AeroNet",
        "slug": "aeronet"
      },
      "provider_account": null,
      "type": {
        "id": 2,
        "url": "http://.../circuits/circuit-types/2/...",
        "display": "Wireless",
        "name": "Wireless",
        "slug": "wireless"
      },
      "status": {
        "value": "active",
        "label": "Active"
      },
      "tenant": {
        "id": 1003,
        "url": "http://.../tenancy/tenants/1003/...",
        "display": "FS297 Puerto Rico Wireless Inc",
        "name": "FS297 Puerto Rico Wireless Inc",
        "slug": "fs_custnum-297"

And I want to create discovered items with name of tenant and id, can someone help me with the Javascript code, I can't parse it correctly.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
